# Java get class constant for closed generic type (instance of Class<T1<T2>>)

Tags: java, generics, jackson, nested-generics

I come from a C# background and am having trouble with Java generics. I am trying to call a generic method that requires an instance of `Class<T>` as a param. Normally this is a matter of passing `SimpleType.class`. In this case though, the type I need is not a simple type, but has its own type parameter that needs to be included in the `Class` instance (i.e. I need a `Class<OuterType<InnerType>>`). How do I get this?

Note: To make things a bit more complicated, this is taking place within another generic method. So while the "outer" type is known at compile type, the inner is known only through its own `Class` instance. See the code:

```
public <T> T deserialize(InputStream stream, Class<T> clazz) {
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper mapper = getJsonMapper();
    //Need an instance of Class<MessageWrapper<T>>
    MessageWrapper<T> wrapper = mapper.readValue(stream, MessageWrapper.class);
    return wrapper.message;
}

private class MessageWrapper<T> {
    public T message;
}
```

Comment: You could just cast it using `(MessageWrapper<T>) mapper.readValue(stream, MessageWrapper.class);`, and then suppress the warning

Comment: @Ferrybig In this case, the warning is there for a reason. The `readValue` method needs to know what T is so that it can map the json properties correctly. Without it it's throwing an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can try is this:

```
public <T> T deserialize(InputStream stream, Class<T> clazz) {
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper mapper = getJsonMapper();
    //Need an instance of Class<MessageWrapper<T>>
    MessageWrapper<T> wrapper =mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<MessageWrapper<T>>() {});
    return wrapper.message;
}
```

As well, the class should be or static, or public within its own file:

```
public class MessageWrapper<T> {
    public T message;
}
```

Or:

```
private static class MessageWrapper<T> {
    public T message;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. This throws an exception though: "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of <NAME_OF_CLASS>$MessageWrapper: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)"

Comment: Try with a static class or a public one within its own java file.